# Wordpress - Insert images to post without Insert Media Window

Tags: wordpress, image

Is it possible to insert images to a Wordpress site with having to use the Insert Media window.

I have a forum type site where I would like people to be able to add images to post they can create but I don't want them to be able to create Galleries of images etc.

I would just like the ability to add images from there system to the post like you can do on forums.

Is this at all possible.

Comment: If you already created your custom form for post insertion then better look at this function [wp_handle_upload](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload) which handles uploads and move them uploads directory explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in WordPress 3.9 you can drag and drop directly into `wp_editor()` - no need for media library so you can hide the button entirely on that post type. Another option is to limit the user-role to what they can and can't do when it comes to the media library. Check out this answer over at the [WordPress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85351/remove-other-tabs-in-new-wordpress-media-gallery)

Finally, you can probably limit what the user sees in the media library, meaning only limit it to what they've uploaded to that post. You can use this code below:

```
/** Media Library - Only Show Images Uploaded To This Post **/
function media_library_filter(){ 
    ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).on("DOMNodeInserted", function(){
            jQuery('select.attachment-filters [value="uploaded"]').attr( 'selected', true ).parent().trigger('change');
        });
      </script>
    <?php 
}
add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'media_library_filter' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'media_library_filter' );

/** Hide Media Library DDL **/
function hide_select_ddl(){
    ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            div.media-menu a.media-menu-item:nth-child(3) {display:none!important;}
            .media-frame-content .attachment-filters:first-child {
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_select_ddl' );
```

What the above code does it only show images uploaded to the current post. You could go further and before the script is ran, decide to only run it on a `post-type` or only on a certain `user-role`. Hopefully this helps!